# Aligning item numbers in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I am taking notes on a textbook, and want to mimic the style used in the book. I have gotten very close, and only have one minor issue left to fix. Consider the example below. The only thing that I don't like is that the article numbers in the table of contents are not aligned. I want all of the article numbers to line up at the period. I tried doing this with a flush-right box as shown in the commented line in the preamble, but I got some error that I don't understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newenvironment{article}[1]{\item\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\arabic{enumi}. #1}}{}
    % \newenvironment{article}[1]{\item\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\makebox[2em][r]{\arabic{enumi}.} #1}}{}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*. , leftmargin = 0pt]

\section{topic 1}

\subsection{subtopic 1.1}

\begin{article}{article title 1} article text 1 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 2} article text 2 \end{article}

\subsection{subtopic 1.2}

\begin{article}{article title 3} article text 3 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 4} article text 4 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 5} article text 5 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 6} article text 6 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 7} article text 7 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 8} article text 8 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 9} article text 9 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 10} article text 10 \end{article}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question completely but you could try `\newenvironment{article}[1]{\item\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\makebox[1.5em][r]{\arabic{enumi}.} #1}}{}`.  Note the `\protect`.  Also, why the `article` environment? That could be just a macro declared via `\newcommand`.

Comment: Adding \protect did the trick, thanks! If you make it an answer, I will endorse it. In actual usage, the contents of the article are about one page long; I omitted this consideration to make my MWE. Is there a reason to prefer a command rather than an environment in this situation?

Comment: I don't understand why your articles couldn't simply be subsubsections?

Comment: Perhaps I can use subsubsections. The requirements are that subsections are not numbered, but subsubsections are numbered, and that the numbering of subsubsections continue across sections and subsections: that is, I have about 200 articles that should be numbered 1-200, even though numbered sections and unnumbered subsections are placed amongst the articles. Let me reiterate that I am trying to match the style used by a textbook, and I did not design this convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comment to answer as requested:

You need to add a `\protect` to the `\makebox`:

[image]

### Notes:

- Not sure what your actual use case is, but for the given MWE I would recommend using a `\newcommand` instead of defining a `\newenvironment.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newenvironment{article}[1]{\item\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\makebox[2em][r]{\arabic{enumi}.} #1}}{}
    %\newenvironment{article}[1]{\item\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\makebox[2em][r]{\arabic{enumi}.} #1}}{}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*. , leftmargin = 0pt]

\section{topic 1}

\subsection{subtopic 1.1}

\begin{article}{article title 1} article text 1 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 2} article text 2 \end{article}

\subsection{subtopic 1.2}

\begin{article}{article title 3} article text 3 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 4} article text 4 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 5} article text 5 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 6} article text 6 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 7} article text 7 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 8} article text 8 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 9} article text 9 \end{article}
\begin{article}{article title 10} article text 10 \end{article}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```